# stacked bar chart want to pair mismatched data python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I have two lists that I want to combine into one stacked bar chart with labels.

```
Males = [('Surfing', 832), ('Swimming', 653), ('Fishing', 314), 
         ('Spearfishing', 299), ('Bathing', 132), ('Diving', 102), 
         ('Wading', 89), ('Standing', 70), ('Scuba diving', 65)]

Females = [('Swimming', 141), ('Wading', 53), ('Surfing', 45), 
           ('Snorkeling', 33), ('Standing', 27), ('Bathing', 16), 
           ('Scuba diving', 9), ('Boogie boarding', 8), ('Walking', 8)]
```

I want it so that the graph will display the total number of people in each activity, while showing the gender breakdown in different colours. However as the order of the lists do not match and neither do all the activities i.e only women were 'walking' and there was no male equivalent. This bar then should appear on its own.

The code  I have written cannot do this. Please just give me general guidelines. Can I use a for loop to go over each element and and an if statement to see if it's also present in the the other gender data? And if so add them together.

I really don't understand how this could be done with an unknown number of bars possible.

Comment: If you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) there's a relatively simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment there is a fairly simple solution for this using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Basically you would put each set of data into a dataframe and then do an outer merge on the activities. I'm not including code because you specifically asked for just guidelines.

The result of that:

[image]

If you can't use pandas for whatever reason you can make an [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and populate that with your female and male data in a list for example. So the keys to the ordered dictionary would be the activities and the values would be a regular dictionary containing a mapping of activity to count. Then it would be simple to plot each of those. Again I'm not including code because you specifically asked for just guidelines.

Here's the result:

[image]